# Failing DVD playback on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, dvd, windows-media-player

System: Windows 7 Home Premium x64, brand new HW.

The machine rejects to play a few DVD-s. It is consistent on what to reject. Some DVD-s are fine, they are always fine. Some are rejected, they are always rejected.

All DVD-s played fine on my old XP machine.

The DVD-s are also backed up as ISO files on the hard drive, and can be played via virtual DVD drives. The result is the same. The non-tasty DVD-s are rejected, the tasty ones are accepted to be played via the virtual drive.

I have installed no extra codecs or player software besides Winamp and iTunes for movies. So I just use the default Windows Media Player and the codecs shipped with Windows 7.

Some more hints: The computer has been purchased in Europe, as well as the DVD-s, so I do not believe that this is a region issue. One of the DVD says in it title NTSC, but I have no idea how could digital DVD content be NTSC (or PAL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try an alternative media player that doesn't require any codecs to be installed (e.g. [SMPlayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/)) and see if the problem persists.

*if you get the portable version, it doesn't even have to be installed on your system, can be used from a USB stick. SMPlayer works with Windows x64.*

Answer (score 0):

this is more likely to be a stuffed drive. I would try doing a firmware update in case its just a glitch in the way it handles DRM'ed disks.